# Question about converting a DataTable to JSON

Tags: c#, datatable

I'm trying to convert a DataTable to a JSON text but I'm having issue if one of the columns has a table type of data.

```
DataTable TaskDetails = new DataTable(); //subtable
TaskDetails.Columns.Add("taskId", typeof(string));
TaskDetails.Columns.Add("ticketUid", typeof(string));
TaskDetails.Rows.Add(TaskID, TicketUID);

DataTable table = new DataTable(); //main table
table.Columns.Add("operationType", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("comment", typeof(string));
table.Columns.Add("tasks", typeof(DataTable));

table.Rows.Add(OperationType,Comment,TaskDetails); //TaskDetails table is added on the main table.

System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer serializer = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer();
List<Dictionary<string, object>> rows = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
Dictionary<string, object> row;
foreach (DataRow dr in table.Rows)
{
    row = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    foreach (DataColumn col in table.Columns)
    {
        row.Add(col.ColumnName, dr[col]);
    }
    rows.Add(row);
}
 string response = serializer.Serialize(rows); //I'm getting an error here
```

Error: System.InvalidOperationException A circular reference was detected while serializing an object of type 'System.Reflection.RuntimeModule

I'm expecting to have string output with Json format.

Comment: Why are you using a DataTable for this at all? Why not just create some classes that represent the information, then serialize those classes?

Comment: can you give an example? I'm a bit lost on how to do it.

Comment: Which part are you lost on? Do you know how to make a class? How to add properties to a class? How to assign values to those properties? How to serialize a given class to JSON?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because you have two objects that are both referencing each other. For example you couldn't serialize the below object "ClassA":

```
ClassA --> ClassB --> ClassA --> ClassB --> ClassA etc.
```

This is called a "circular dependency" because ClassA is dependent on ClassB, and ClassB is dependent on ClassA. You can't serialize this because the generated Json would be infinitely long.

So instead you need to use the data from these rows to create your own serializable objects that do not have these circular references.

Comment: can you give an example? I'm a bit lost on how to do it.